# import pytz failing in eclipse - python

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7

I am trying to import pytz  in eclipse(Juno) but it fails.

```
import pytz
```

error

```
    import pytz
ImportError: No module named pytz
```

I read somewhere in the forums that, the below code helps in trouble shooting the issue

```
import sys
print sys.executable
```

output

```
C:\My\Location\Python\python.exe
```

Can anyone please advise how to fix the issue?

Comment: You have to install the module first ;). Go [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pytz/), download the files, then run the `setup.py` script by doing `python setup.py install`

Comment: hey mate , no alternate solutions ?;) Don't have the dl or install rights on this M/C :D

Comment: Sorry, none that I am aware :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to install pytz.  But you say you don't have admin rights on the PC, so you will have to "install" it to a directory you do have rights in.  For example, you can install pytz into `My Documents\Python` and then set the `PYTHONPATH` environment to point there, and Python will load pytz from your personal space rather than only considering the system locations.